# How to add dependencies to an rpm built by python

Tags: python, rpm, setuptools

I am trying to create an rpm of a python package using `setuptools`. Using the following command on linux:

```
$ python setup.py bdist --formats=rpm
```

The RPM builds fine; however, the requirement (cryptography), does not appear as a dependency in the RPM.

Is there any way to specify which dependencies this package requires?

The `setup.py` file looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(
        name="dummy",
        version=0.1,
        description="This is a dummy package",
        install_requires=[
            "cryptography>=1.3.4",
        ],
    )
```

Comment: It is much better to use pyp2rpm to create the rpm.

Comment: @msuchy Interesting! I didn't know about this. I will investigate further.